# Why can I use If Else syntax and not a ternary operator?

Tags: c#, linq, if-statement, ternary-operator

Why can I do this?

```
if (integerList.Direction == "ascending") { 
    integerList.Integers.OrderBy(i => i.IntegerValue);
} else{
    integerList.Integers.OrderByDescending(i => i.IntegerValue);
}
```

But not this?

```
integerList.Direction == "ascending" ? integerList.Integers.OrderBy(i => i.IntegerValue)
                                     : integerList.Integers.OrderByDescending(i => i.IntegerValue);
```

It returns the error:

```
only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await and new object expressions can be used as a statement.
```

Comment: Because that is not how C# works.  The ternary operator must make an assignment.

Comment: @musical_coder Actually in C# the `==` operator *on `string`* performs a value rather than a reference comparison.

Comment: @rae1n: I remember reading that somewhere once, so I deleted my comment. However, this Microsoft guide discourages that and instead uses `Equals`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc165449.aspx.

Comment: Actually @musical_coder, the behavior of the `==` operator is the same as the `Equals` method, since [`==` calls `Equals` as it is implementation for the `string` class](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System/String.cs). Any discouragement would be based on personal appeal or readability, which can quite subjective (or in your case to avoid confusion as to its behavior). But I'll have to admit I'm getting quite fond of using `Equals`, at least in some cases...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this code makes a call to a given *operation* (regardless of the branch) which is in itself a statement, thus allowed,

```
if (integerList.Direction == "ascending") { 
    integerList.Integers.OrderBy(i => i.IntegerValue);
} else{
    integerList.Integers.OrderByDescending(i => i.IntegerValue);
}
```

Using the ternary operator, however, you end up with an expression, which by itself it is not allowed, as it is considered a no-op, except of course, like the error says, it is a *new object expression*,

```
integerList.Direction == "ascending" 
    ? integerList.Integers.OrderBy(i => i.IntegerValue)
    : integerList.Integers.OrderByDescending(i => i.IntegerValue);
```

The result of the operation it is not actually consumed, so the entire `OrderBy` is wasted.

Try this instead,

```
var intergersOrdered = 
    integerList.Direction == "ascending" 
        ? integerList.Integers.OrderBy(i => i.IntegerValue)
        : integerList.Integers.OrderByDescending(i => i.IntegerValue);
```

which turns the ternary operator into an assignment statement.

Answer (score 2):

The ternary operator in C# is an *operator* not a statement.  You need to use it in a statement with something to receive the return value.

Read [this answer by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10784447/571637).

Answer (score 1):

Because by definition a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a) is an assignment operator, or more accurately a *conditional* assignment operator. It assigns different values according according to the supplied condition. It doesn't *execute* statements. While you can definitely unfold any ternary construct into an if-then-else construct, the reverse is not true.

Answer (score 1):

While the fact remains that the ternary operator is a conditional assignment operator, you could probably still do this

```
var values = integerList.Direction == "ascending" ? integerList.Integers.OrderBy(i => i.IntegerValue)
                                     : integerList.Integers.OrderByDescending(i => i.IntegerValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to think about the difference between if-else and the ternary operator:

- If-else allows you to decide which **block of code** will be executed.
- The ternary operator helps you decide between two objects or values (of the same type) to use **inside a  single statement**.

The reason you are getting a compiler error for your ternary operator is because the rules of the language: the Ternary operator returns a value.  But values are used *in* statements; they are not themselves statements.  Consider:

```
int x = 1;

// Both these lines are invalid because a string literal is not a complete statement:
"x is an integer";
x < 0 ? "x is Negative" : "x is not Negative";

//Valid:
string intDescription = "x is an integer";
string describeNegative = x < 0 ? "x is Negative" : "x is not Negative";

// Invalid because the ternary operator chooses between values, and Console.WriteLine
// is void:
x < 0 ? Console.WriteLine("x is Negative") : Console.WriteLine("x is not Negative");

// Valid:
Console.WriteLine(x < 0 ? "x is Negative" : "x is not Negative");
// or:
string describeNegative = x < 0 ? "x is Negative" : "x is not Negative";
Console.WriteLine(describeNegative);
```

---

Now hopefully you understand the Ternary operator a bit better.  Unfortunately, there's another problem with your code.  Even though this compiles, it doesn't actually do anything:

```
if (integerList.Direction == "ascending") { 
    integerList.Integers.OrderBy(i => i.IntegerValue);
} else{
    integerList.Integers.OrderByDescending(i => i.IntegerValue);
}
```

OrderBy creates a new object that is an `IOrderedEnumerable<YourIntegerClass>` and contains the same contents that `Integers` did, but sorted.  OrderBy returns this new object and leaves your original container unchanged.  This is a relatively common pattern with the Linq extension methods, although most return IEnumerable objects instead of IOrderedEnumerable.

Instead of only making a copy that you don't do anything with, I'm guessing you want to sort the contents of `Integers`; to do that, you need to assign that result of the OrderBy back to the `Integers` object:

```
if (integerList.Direction == "ascending") { 
    //I'm guessing that Integers is a List, so I've added .ToList() as well here:
    integerList.Integers = integerList.Integers.OrderBy(i => i.IntegerValue).ToList();
} else{
    integerList.Integers = integerList.Integers.OrderByDescending(i => i.IntegerValue).ToList();
}
```

Because you are choosing between two values (in this case, for assignment to `Integers`) you can use the ternary operator:

```
integerList.Integers = integerList.Direction == "ascending" 
    ? integerList.Integers.OrderBy(i => i.IntegerValue).ToList()
    : integerList.Integers.OrderByDescending(i => i.IntegerValue).ToList();
```